# Asp.Net MVC Not Duplicate forms when Edit/Add

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

When we have anything that requires user input (Eg adding a product to a database) the Edit screen looks the same as the add screen. When using MVC .Net how do you handle this? Do you return the same view? Just adjust the model to reflect the change?

Comment: Your approach to return the same view seems reasonable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Same (partial)view

You create only one but **strong typed** view (depending on the UI it can of course be a partial view as well). When adding new data return this view from controller action with default model object instance (usually just a new instance without any properties being set), but when you edit, return it with the object instance that you'd like to edit.

### Controller part

Regarding controller actions you can have four of them:

1. Add GET
   `return View("SomeView", new Customer());`
2. Add POST
3. Edit GET
   `return View("SomeView", new CustomerRepository().GetCustomer(id));`
4. Edit POST

Bot GET actions return the same view but with different model as described earlier. POST actions both store submitted data, but return whatever they need to. Probably some `RedirectToAction()`...

Comment: Protip: Name your POST and GET methods the same and don't set the action attribute on your form. The page will post to itself (and the correct Add or Edit method).

Comment: @Ryan: Of course. Both are `Add()` but one defines `[HttpPost]` attribute as well and receives an additional parameter. And the same for `Edit()` actions. This is the most common approach with Asp.net MVC anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the same view for display and Edit, simply call it from your controller

```
return View("ViewName")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have the form fields in a partial view and have two separate views using the same partial view, one posting to the edit controller action method and the other posting to the add controller action method.

Answer (score 1):

Partial views are used to remove duplicity. You could read an example of this in the [Nerd Dinner tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx).